# TinyMCE: Overriding bold and italic defined in stylesheet

Tags: css, tinymce

Consider the following example

editor css:

```
.heading{
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="heading"> This is main heading </div>
```

When I try to remove the bold from whole whole text inside the heading div it won't convert it to normal text. This might be because of the font-weight defined in heading class. Is there a way to toggle the font-weight for such cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get ride of this issue we moved font styling (bold, italic) out from CSS and used the `<strong>` and `<i>` tags directly into the content. This seems to be only proper way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to change the `font-weight` back to normal? If so, just delete that line of CSS, or set the property to `font-weight:normal;`

Comment: Font-weight is bold by default in css. However, user don't have access to css, she can only edit content in TinyMCE editor. I want to allow user to set back it to normal if she wants using the editor **Bold** button.